# Compile scala code mix with java code

Tags: scala, jar, executable-jar

I need to compile a scala code which calls a java code from it.

**What I did:**

1]I have a scala main file `check.scala`

```
package com.code
     class check {
       var Rectvalue = Array.ofDim[Int](5)
       val str = Array.ofDim[String](1)
       def nativeacces(arg: String, loop: Integer) {
         val test = new testing()
         test.process(arg, Rectvalue,str)
         }
     }
```

2.For creating instance ***val test = new testing()*** ,i added two .class(sample.class,testJNI.class) file from java source code inside the folder(package) com/code.

3.When I compile the scala code using

```
scalac check.scala
```

It generates the class file for the scala file.

**What I have to do:**

1.Instead of .class(sample.class,testJNI.class) file added inside the package ,i need to add jar file.

2.I tried, created jar file for the `.class` file and compile the Scala, it shows the error:

```
 scala:6: error: not found: type testing
 val test = new testing()
```

3.I need to link the `.jar` file and compile the scala main file

Comment: use `–classpath` to reference your JAR. Even better let SBT handle all that.

Comment: @Aleksey Izmailo ,thanks for your reply.Can you please expain it in detail or help me with any links.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference classes/directories/JARs via `classpath` option:

```
scalac -classpath your.jar check.scala
```

Related question: [Adding .jar's to classpath (Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077899/adding-jars-to-classpath-scala).

If you want a proper build use SBT, put your JAR in `lib` directory in the root of project and it will figure out what to do for you. [Here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html) is Hello World of SBT.

Comment: thanks for the reply,I used package com.code in the project whether it change for that...